# How can I grab a value from a list? Python and Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

```
def take_all_screenshots(self):
 Base_URL = "URL HERE"
 pages = ['urlhere1',
          'urlhere2',
          'urlhere3',
          ]

 for page in pages:
    self.driver.get(Base_URL + page)
    pagename = "%s" %str(page)
    name = pagename + str(datetime.datetime.now()) + '.png'
    self.driver.save_screenshot('screenshots/%s' % name)
```

How can I grab the URL from the list to add to the screenshot name?
Currently it only grabs the first one, please help!

Comment: I want the screenshot names to come out as "urlhere1+datetime.png"

Comment: what is your current output?

Comment: It takes one screenshot only of the first url

Comment: The urls are being grabbed from the list. Try inserting a print statement to print out the `name` before the last line of the for loop, you will see different urls there. It seems your `self.driver` is not taking the other urls.

Comment: Tried this and it is still saving only one screenshot for the first item in the list. If i take out the page then it saves all screenshots with the date + time. for page in pages:
        self.driver.get(Base_URL + page)
        pagename = str(page)
        name = pagename + str(datetime.datetime.now()) + '.png'
        print name
        self.driver.save_screenshot('screenshots/%s' % name)

Answer (score 1):

Hi Automation Enthusiast,

To get an item from a list, use `listname[index]`. Keep in mind that indexes start at 0 and count up by 1.

To concatenate two strings, use `string1 + string2`.

To change the filename to the result, use `os.rename("original/filename/and/file.path","new/filename/and/file.path")`.

Hope this helps, BoxTechy

Comment: How do I make this grab each page as it runs through the loop? name = str(pages[0]) + str(datetime.datetime.now()) + '.png'

Comment: @AutomationEnthusiast You can use variables as well as integers. Try pages[page] instead.

Comment: pages[page]
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str

Comment: @AutomationEnthusiast Wait, I just realized that you're iterating through the list! Just call page itself. Sorry.

Comment: I tried that, for some reason it only grabs the first one & doesn't take anymore screenshots after

Comment: @AutomationEnthusiast I can't identify what's going on. Your code is definitely correct. Try just running `print(page)` to see if Python is working properly.

Comment: hmmm, only prints the first one

Answer (score 0):

If the loop is within the same scope you could try:

```
def take_all_screenshots(self):
    Base_URL = "URL HERE"
    pages = ['urlhere1',
             'urlhere2',
             'urlhere3',
            ]

    for page in pages:
        #Why have a getter() that returns nothing
        #self.driver.get(Base_URL + page)
        pagename = "%s" %str(page)
        name = pagename + str(datetime.datetime.now()) + '.png'
        self.driver.save_screenshot('screenshots/%s' % name)
```

`for page in pages:` will return the correct item in the list